# Android MediaCodec decode is SUPER SLOW

Tags: android, decode, android-mediacodec, qualcomm

Android MediaCodec decode takes a super long time, about 115 to 118 msecs per frame. This is a h264 frame. The Android device has a qualcomm snapdragon 845 processor, so I assume the Android MediaCodec APIs target the qualcomm GPU and not the ARM core CPU.
Wondering if anyone has experienced such issue/s before and can provide guidance on how to make this decode go faster?

The code is all native code, no java at all. With no Java, I have no active window, no surface texture... so Grafika examples don't help here. I am using AndroidP(9.0) API 28. NDK 19.2.5x.

Here's how my code is setup:

Step1: I have two codec instances configured on two separate threads as follows:

```
codecData.codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType("video/avc");
AMediaFormat_setString(codecData.format_eye, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
AMediaFormat_setInt32(codecData.format_eye, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, 1920);
AMediaFormat_setInt32(codecData.format_eye, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, 1080);
AMediaFormat_setFloat(codecData.format_eye, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_FRAME_RATE, 60.0f);
```

Step2: I enqueue the encoded buffer using these calls which take 14 to 17 msecs on 60 FPS input with two separate threads populating the individual codec Qs:

```
bufIdx = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(codecData.codec, -1); //-1 makes it blocking call
auto buf = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer(codecData.codec, bufIdx, &bufSize);
uint64_t presentTime = presentTimer.getTimeUs();
memcpy(buf, data, size);
AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(codecData.codec, bufIdx, 0, size, presentTime, 0);
```

Step3: I dequeue the decoded buffer as follows, these takes 115 to 118 msecs per frame per codec on 60 FPS output. The dequeue for both the codecs are done by one consumer thread which goes through both the codec instances one at a time:

```
AMediaCodecBufferInfo info_eye;
bufIdx = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer(codecData.codec, &info_eye, 1);
auto decodedBuf = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(codecData.codec, bufIdx, &bufSize);
```

Step4: The decoded buffer is then fed to a NV12toRGBA shader on the render thread that populates the texture which takes about 2 msecs. This texture then gets displayed.

I am expecting 60 FPS but get about 50 FPS due to the delays in Step3 i.e. the 115 to 118 msecs latency is killing me :-(

Any ideas? Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Did you find any solution?